# A function continuously differentiable that is bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $ \mathbb R$, but the continuous inverse is not differentiable.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f$ is continuously differentiable and bijection and has a inverse function $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, but $g$ is not differentiable everywhere?

I compare it with the inverse theorem and found that the difference is that the differentiable function of $f$ doesn't have to be invertible, but I am struggling to find such a function.

Answer (score 7):

$f(x)=x^3$ foots the bill. It is bijective, its derivative $f'(x)=3x^2$ is continuous (differentiable, actually), and $f^{-1}(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Wouldn't any function with derivative $0$ at some point have this property?

Comment: Absolutely. That's how I thought of the example: some easy function, bijective, with derivative equal to zero at some point.

Comment: Yes because if the inverse is differentiable by the chain rule the derivative is nonzero.

Comment: @ruler501: The OP is looking for bijective functions. So, for example, $f(x) = x^2$ is not bijective, but $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: So the answer is any bijective function whose derivative is $0$ at some point.